# Conditional discount in woocommerce with credit card payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, discount

I am developing an online store based on woocommerce and I have some question.
The website will be sponsored by some credit card providers and I want to give the discount to customer who purchases with the credit card that the website is sponsored by.

At the moment, I am using Stripe payment gate way (paid version) and I wonder if there is anyway I can add such conditional discount on to the website or is there any either free or paid add-on that allows me to still use Stripe as payment gateway and work with the conditional discount.

Any answer will be appreciated.
Thank you,
Scott

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are free plugin that can help you such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-payment-discounts/. But if you're looking for something more professional with a many other discounts types, i suggest you check this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-advanced-discounts/ with the discount per payment gateway available in their pro version.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is very useful :) You have saved my life!